# Is there a way to try out my Pokemon moves if I am home, not next to a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way to try the different movesets of different Pokemon; can I stay home and try them out?

Do I have to physically be outside next to a gym?  It might be raining outside or it might be 11pm and I just want to play a little without having to drive outside.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way to battle if you are not close enough to a gym. Trying out your moves is also not possible any other way.

Of course, Niantic might add a new feature in the future, but currently there is none.

Answer (score 3):

While you are unable to simulate a battle to see how moves look, you can see a move's stats and attributes to determine what best suits you or your needs.

To see a list of stats for each move, you can look [here](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/moves.shtml). However, since the moves' damage and subsequent energy increase has been changed, this site has outdated numbers. To see updated energy gains, look at this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vcobt/posthotfix_pokemon_go_full_moveset_rankings/d5xxrfg?st=irwag3hm&sh=18860cb0).

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can compare the moves you got with other moves using this table:

https://goo.gl/SEBo2y

Here you can check which pokémons movesets are the best compared to other movesets that all other pokémons has.

In the episode below, he explains how to use the spreadsheet and why is that so important to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit it and try to look out the next time I answer. Thanks mate!